# Не получается добавить библиотеку при сборке проекта

Tags: java, jar

Здравствуйте,есть класс,который подключается к базе данных.
C помощью eclipse создаю jar файл в котором этот класс и mysql connection,при запуске jar я постоянно вижу ошибку `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc:Driver` подскажите,что я делаю не правильно?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

        public class Solution1 {
            private static Connection connection = null;
            private static Statement statement = null;
            private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Example");
                    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

в итоге jar содержит:

1. пакет main в котором класс
2. jar файл connection
3. папка МЕТА-INF(сгенерирована автоматически)

Comment: Добавьте код подключения, код использования и т.д.

Comment: что,совсем нет мыслей почему ошибка?

Comment: Ну.... Не подключен класс.

Comment: Если попробовать прописать импорт, выйдет? Вообще такой класс есть?

Comment: @RostislavDugin дабавил и импорты.
дело в том что в эклипсе всё работает нормально,проблема возникает только когда я создаю jar файл

Comment: Так чего же Вы сразу не сказали!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что, когда Вы собираете проект, библиотеки и не добавляются в конечный исполняемый файл.

Для того, чтобы работал Ваш исполняемый файл:

1. Или пропишите путь к .jar в пути запуска.
2. Или добавьте в pom.xml (если Вы используете Maven:

   ```
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <mainClass>com.пакет.Main</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
               <descriptorRefs>
                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>make-assembly</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```

   Main
                       
                   
                   
                       jar-with-dependencies
                   
               
               
                   
                       make-assembly
                       package
                       
                           single

Или же Вы можете вынести все зависимости в отдельную папку:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Я так понимаю в pom.xml Вы запаковываете в один .jar-ник все зависимости?

Comment: @I.Perevoz, да.